# FCP X 10.1.1 - Transitioning to libraries without blending

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

As excited as I am about the new asset management possibilities of the .1 release of Final Cut Pro X, I'm nervous about screwing up my existing projects and events. My projects and events are currently spread across 2 hard drives (my boot drive and an external drive). Some are "hidden" via Event Manager X. Some projects and events belong together, and others do not. I performed the upgrade to FCP X 10.1.1 (apparently they've already released some bug fixes to 10.1.0). When I did this, I kept my projects and events "hidden".

Now it's time to import them, but I want to make sure I pair the correct projects and events in the correct libraries. (In other words, I want to have 1 library for each client, not 1 library for each hard drive, nor 1 library for each project.) There is not an menu option for importing and pairing projects and events—at least not that I can find. How can I conduct combine projects and events into libraries in a controlled way?

Comment: I've seen some tutorials for upgrading to libraries which make use of Event Manager X floating around the internet.  Perhaps that's a good direction to look into.  Haven't tried it myself, so I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work. The key is to update Events and Projects to Libraries (which, incidentally, contain Events and Projects) in stages:

1. Hide everything except the Events and Projects that belong together in the same Library. Event Manager X is a great tool for this, as Jason suggested in the comments. Whatever tool you use, just make sure that only the Events and Projects that belong together are in the folders "Final Cut Events" and "Final Cut Projects".
2. Next, open Final Cut Pro X.
3. Go to File and click "Update Projects and Events..." near the bottom of the menu:[image: Update Projects and Events]
4. Click "Update All"

Final Cut Pro X will do its thing and you'll have a new library with just the Projects and Events you want inside of it.

Comment: In reality, the stakes are lower than I realized when I wrote my question. You can still move Events and Projects between Libraries after upgrading. In other words, upgrading to 10.1 doesn't destroy Events and Projects and replace them with Libraries. It places Events and Projects inside of Libraries.

Comment: Excellent, glad it worked out for you.  Thanks for sharing what you found.  I live in a Windows world, so I can only experience FCP vicariously.